# How does one implement dark/transparent text-boxes?

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to implement 'the dark/transparent' text-boxes on-top of the background (example: http://trishkhoo.com/2013/04/i-knew-exactly-how-she-felt/)

Please see the heading displayed in the above link:

*"I knew exactly how she felt
Filed Under: Random musings by Trish Khoo — 5 Comments" it is in a darker but yet transparent box.*

How can this be achieved with simple css/html?

I hope this is an appropriate place to ask this. Stackoverflow has been my go-to-source for design/development related questions thus far! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you mean a simple DIV with a semi-transparent background color right?

you can try with this:

```
.box{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* where 0.5 means 50% opacity */
/* and for a full compatibility on older browsers like ie7-8-9 you can use the filter property  */
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */
      zoom: 1;

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FR6LY/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You would just use `background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)`  This will make a black box with 50% opacity

rgba stands for Red Green Blue Alpha and the numbers afterwards correspond to those letters.  0,0,0, means zero red, zero green, zero blue and the last number is a 0 - 1 number where 0.5 is 50%, etc.

The way they are doing it on that page is using a 1px by 1px .png with transparency.  Unfortunately, you can not change how transparent the black is without making an entirely new image to stretch (or repeat).  With RGBA, you get the same outcome, but you can control the color and alpha.

Answer (score 1):

It uses `background-image` property to achieve that effect. It is an 1x1 pixels image with transparency that repeats on x and y.

Image used: http://trishkhoo.com/wp-content/themes/motion/images/blacktrans.png

You do not need to use a image but some browsers do not support alpha factor when applying colors with **`rgba(r,g,b,a)` css function** so this is the best cross-browser option in my opinion.

Comment: @anonymous can you explain the downvote? Maybe you think that cross browser compatibility is not important